# Can I have multiple values in one HTML "data-" element?

Tags: html, css

Can I have multiple values in one HTML "data-" element? Similar to how a class can have multiple class names.

If possible, I would like to create a CSS/JS library that makes use of one "data-" element to house all of the library styles. For example:

```
<div data-library-name="xs-hidden col-md-10 col-xl-8 big-hero"></div>
```

That way, any of the programmers custom style rules can go into the elements class. My reasoning for this is to make readability easier, so together it would look like:

```
<div class="custom-style another-style" data-library-name="xs-hidden col-md-10 col-xl-8 big-hero"></div>
```

Comment: Your data-library-name attribute will have one value, not four unique values.

Comment: Yes and no. It would be a single data attribute value, but you could split them into separate values with JavaScript.

Comment: You can put a "split" character between the values like an `*` or maybe `|`

Answer (score 43):

> Can I have multiple values in one HTML "data-" element?

You can have a string. The spec doesn't define any particular format for the data in the attribute, which is designed to be processed by *site specific* JavaScript.

> Similar to how a class can have multiple class names.

The class attribute takes a space separated list of classes.

Your JavaScript can `your_data_attribute_value.split(" ");` if you like.

Handling this with CSS would use the `~=` [attribute selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors).

> **[att~=val]**
>   Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains whitespace, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). Also if "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything.

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK, I don't think `data-` attributes can convert that to an array. Instead, I think it'll interpret it as one value, but it *is* allowed.

If you want to do that, you'll probably have to `split()` it later in JavaScript into an array of usable values.

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/jlam55555/hczL0rnv/) on JSFiddle.net.

Answer (score 7):

CSS has the shortcut `.class` selector but it actually is parsing the attribute named "class" as a list for space separated values. This is supported in the non-shortcut form by the following attribute selector:

> **`[att~=val]`**
>
> Represents an element with the att attribute whose value is a white space-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "val". If "val" contains white space, it will never represent anything (since the words are separated by spaces). If "val" is the empty string, it will never represent anything either.

Ref: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#class-html

As your question is tagged CSS you're perhaps looking for that. The rules how the parsing of attribute values is done is given in that document as well, so in case the javascript library you're trying to use on this (if any) won't cover that, it should be easy to add:

```
var list = $("div").data("library-name").split(/\s+/);
                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This split with the white-space regular expression parses the string attribute value into an array with javascript and the Jquery library (for accessing the DOM and the data attribute).